# XMLHttpRequest no answer from server

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have tried to get i connection to an php file but i don't recive any reponse from server is anything wrong?,

```
function request(){
    // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
var url = "http://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/courses/05_ass/ip3/3/3.7.1/example.php";
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
var vars = "?number1="+number1+"&number2="+number2
hr.open("POST", url, true);

// Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
// Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
   var return_data = hr.responseText;

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = return_data;
}
}
// Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
hr.send(vars); // Actually execute the request
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "processing...";
 }
```

I don't get any answer from the server were have i done wrong?

I have now tried to write it in jquery insteed but still no response from server

```
$(document).ready(function() {

// Skicka nummrerna vid klick på #calculate
$('#calculate').click(function() {

var url = "http://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/courses/05_ass/ip3/3/3.7.1/example.php?";
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1").value;
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2").value;
var numbers = url + number1 + "&" + number2
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// Kod för nya webbläsare
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {//om det inte är en nyare webbläsare
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        // Skriv ut svaret från servern i result
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET",numbers,true);
xmlhttp.send();
alert(numbers);
});
});
```

Comment: how have you checked if you get any answer from server? using a debug console? your code only shows anything if request status is 200 and readystate is 4, so how will you know about other responses?

Comment: Did you looked in the inspector to see if there is an error or not?

Comment: Why don't you use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to simplify your life?

Comment: @RaraituL and that would simplify this how exactly?

Comment: @eis Doesn't fixes the problem, but it solves other problems (like cross-browser issues) for you. And also makes the code smaller

Comment: It makes the amount of code you have to write (in characters) moderately smaller, while adding a huge chunk of library code, most of which you won't use. As for cross-browser, for this situation, jQuery would only add support for IE6, which is ancient and should die in a ditch.

Comment: To reiterate eis: What is the problem. You say you don't get a response from the server. How are you determining this? What debug tools are you using? What results do they show? What errors are you browsers raising? Which browsers are you testing this in? Are they giving consistent results?

Answer (score 2):

You're formatting your variables as if you're using them in a GET request, but then setting your request up for a POST.

[edit: to demonstrate comments]

Try changing these two lines.

```
hr.open("GET", url + vars, true);

hr.send();
```

[edit] Full original code with the changes

```
function request(){
        // Create our XMLHttpRequest object
    var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    // Create some variables we need to send to our PHP file
    var url = "http://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/courses/05_ass/ip3/3/3.7.1/example.php";
    var number1 =22;// document.getElementById("number1").value;
    var number2 =22;// document.getElementById("number2").value;
    var vars = "?number1="+number1+"&number2="+number2
    hr.open("GET", url + vars, true);

    // Set content type header information for sending url encoded variables in the request
    //hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    // Access the onreadystatechange event for the XMLHttpRequest object

    hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
               var return_data = hr.responseText;

                document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = return_data;
            }
    }
    // Send the data to PHP now... and wait for response to update the status div
    hr.send(); // Actually execute the request
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "processing...";
 }
```

Comment: Try removing the leading `?` from `vars`?

Comment: does not work, the request should look like this; http://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/courses/05_ass/ip3/3/3.7.1/example.php?number1=22&number2=22

Comment: Then can you append `vars` to `url` and change to a GET, then remove `vars` from the `.send()`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to send() your request with the data as the param.  Something like:

```
params = "number1="+number1+"&number2="+number2;
hr.send(params);
```

Comment: that didn't work and the request should look like: example.php?number1=22&number2=22

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete code in jQuery format:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calculate').click(function () {
        var url = "http://people.dsv.su.se/~pierre/courses/05_ass/ip3/3/3.7.1/example.php?number1=" + $("#number1").val() + "&number2=" + $("#number2").val();
        $.ajax(url, {
            complete: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //Put the code that handle the response here
                $("#result").html(data.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
});
```